# How do I limit all httpd processes to use less than 90% total CPU?

Tags: apache, cpu, httpd.conf, cgroups

I've looked into nice, cpulimit, and cggroups, but I'm not sure if any of them would do what I want to do. Maybe they do, but I'm doing it wrong.

My end goal is for CentOS to look into all the apache processes, and if they add up to a certain amount of CPU usage, kill the one with the biggest %. Is there such a tool out there that does that, or this is something I have to write a shell/python script and then schedule a cronjob?

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to cgroups and [mod_cgroup](https://github.com/MatthewIfe/mod_cgroup)